# iOS Application screen sizes have black bars on some screens at top and bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, size, screen

Recently I've upgraded to XCode 7 and have been having some trouble with screen sizes on my application, mainly black bars the appear at the top and bottom of the screen.

I've read through similar threads and implemented the fixes suggested which was adding a launch screen image and that worked for my iPhone 6's size but when I try running the simulator for the iPhone 6+ the black bars at the top and bottom of the screen are still there.

Also the screen wont resize for smaller versions either and parts get cut off or go off screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I suggest replacing your launch image with a launch storyboard, and tell us more about how your app is written; do you use autolayout?

Comment: I tried using a launch storyboard and that fixed the problem on my iPhone 6 but on the 6+ it still shows the black bars. I am not using autolayout either.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem last week updating an old app. Adding a launch screen image won't entirely solve it. Instead, you need to create a new launch screen.storyboard (File -> New -> File -> User Interface Tab (on the left) -> Launch Screen

[image]

Then in your project settings, set your launch screen file to the .storyboard file you just created. This should automatically fix the black bars.
[image]

Comment: Ok I just tried that and it fixes the bars on the regular iPhone 6 but not the 6+. Thanks for the in depth tutorial anyways, at least it fixes part of the problem.

Comment: Wait it seems to work fine on actual device but not on simulator, maybe that was the issue. Is this common?

Comment: I wouldn't say common, but iphone simulators definitely aren't known for working perfectly all the time. Out of curiosity, try deleting the app on the simulator and re-running

Comment: YES IT WORKS!!! Thanks sorry for the misunderstanding that actually really helped!

Comment: It works on the simulator now?

Comment: Yes it works on the simulator, also it used to resize everything from the 5 to work on the 6 screen size but now it doesn't?!